# amCharts - XY Charts Tooltip and Bullet

Tags: amcharts

I have an XY Charts in amCharts 4 and I can't set the correct parameter to insert in the tooltip. This is the code that design the chart:

Is possible to show the parameter "desc" in the tooltip?

```js
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [ {
    "x": -6,
    "y": 0,
    "diam": 4,
    "desc": "test"
  }, {
    "x": 0,
    "y": -10,
    "diam": 4,
    "desc": "test"
  }, {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 10,
    "diam": 8,
    "desc": "special"
  } ];

// Create axes
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueX = "x";
series.dataFields.valueY = "y";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.fillOpacity = 0;
series.stroke = "red";

// Create bullet and tooltip
seriesBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
seriesBullet.circle.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
seriesBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 3;
seriesBullet.circle.propertyFields.radius = "diam";
seriesBullet.tooltipText = "desc";
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `desc` in curly braces: `{desc}`

```
seriesBullet.tooltipText = "{desc}";
```

Here is your updated working example:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [ {
    "x": -6,
    "y": 0,
    "diam": 4,
    "desc": "test"
  }, {
    "x": 0,
    "y": -10,
    "diam": 4,
    "desc": "test"
  }, {
    "x": 12,
    "y": 10,
    "diam": 8,
    "desc": "special"
  } ];

// Create axes
var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueX = "x";
series.dataFields.valueY = "y";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.fillOpacity = 0;
series.stroke = "red";
series.tooltipText = "{desc}";

// Create bullet and tooltip
seriesBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
seriesBullet.circle.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
seriesBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 3;
seriesBullet.circle.propertyFields.radius = "diam";
seriesBullet.tooltipText = "{desc}";
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your parameter inside a {} curly braces.
E.g :

```
seriesBullet.tooltipText = "{desc}";
```